# Disable specific bean types from cloud foundry java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

I have the problem that im my company there is a workaround for using the db2 broker in cloud foundry. To get this work you have to disable the java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration in your application with this property:

> JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'

Otherwise you get this error:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-142, SQLSTATE=42612, SQLERRMC=null

In the git project (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration) I read that this property disables re-writes of bean definitions of various types (javax.sql.DataSource, org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory,  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory, ...) to connect automatically with services bound to the application. In our application we use MongoDB as well as DB2. Therefore I am worried about that with this configuration I disable something that I do not want to disable for MongoDB.

I hope this will get fixed soon that I do not need this configuration. But for now is it possible to only disable the reconfiguration for specific bean types (in my case "javax.sql.DataSource")?

Comment: The auto reconfiguration makes use of the deprecated Spring Cloud Connectors. It's probably best to just disable it and use https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv instead. This project is the recommended path going forward for service bindings in your Java apps.

Comment: I can't speak to the error you're seeing. If it's buildpack related, try referencing a Github issue or adding more details here. I can see if it's something possible to fix, but as mentioned in my other comment Spring Cloud Connectors is deprecated so if the issue is in that library it probably will not get fixed and the path forward would be to use java-cfenv instead.

Comment: Thank you. Using java-cfenv is a good solution for me. Unfortunately I have no possibility to give more information about the db2 error because I have not enough permission for analysing.